# protect data validation list content in protected excel speadsheet

Tags: excel

I have a excel spreadsheet which I want to protect. There is a data validation list that use INDIRECT formula to display values from a table. I want the user to be able to select values from that list, but I don't want the user to be able to remove the text displayed in the cell. Can that be done without VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If i understand you correctly you ensure that you have unchecked the locked box for the cells containing the data validation. Right click format cells -> protection ->  uncheck box Locked. And when setting up your data validation ensure you uncheck the Ignore blank box. Then when sheet is protected user can only select from drop down list. They can't delete what is in the cell.

Comment: Hmm, that does not work for me... I can still delete the content of the content.

Comment: Is this in Excel? By unchecking the Ignore blank you are essentially adding a rule that says the cell can't be blank. So you can't delete the data, you get a validation warning and cannot proceed without entering a valid value.

Comment: Yes thats in excel. I tried your approach and then cleared the content in that cell without any issues

Comment: As per the documentation this setting should not allow blanks after a value has been selected from the drop down. It becomes an invalid entry to delete the current entry and leave it blank. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/validation-ignoreblank-property-excel

Comment: Ok, but I can delete the content just fine.

Comment: You can delete and press Enter?

Comment: Yes thats right, then the content is gone leaving a empty cell. And other cells that use a Vlookup refering to that cell wich now is empty has a #NA value instead of the correct value that should have been displayed.